# Disabling Autorotation for Game Center

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, center, game-center, autorotate

I'm trying to implement the Game Center Achievements in my first game. The orientation of my game is landscape left only.

What I have done so far is to change GameConfig.h as below:

```
#if defined(__ARM_NEON__) || TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
#define GAME_AUTOROTATION kGameAutorotationNone

#elif __arm__
#define GAME_AUTOROTATION kGameAutorotationNone
```

My game is then fixed in the Landscape Left orientation at all times. However, when I enter the Game Center Achievement screen from my game, the autorotation is still happening. I am a bit confused with the concept here. Could you guys please tell me why this is happening? And How can I fix this?

Thanks very much in advance. I would really appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Look into your gameview controller or equivalent version of it in your code. Search for the following function:

```
-(BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation ;
```

Comment out the code inside it and only return `NO`.

I hope this will fix your problem... let me know if it's not working.

Comment: I'm sorry that I have just realized someone answered my problem. I have put this problem aside and was working on the other stuff for my first game. I have tried to comment out all the stuff and return NO in the rootViewController as you said. But the autorotation is still happening when I rotate my iPhone. What could the problem be? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in `AppDelegate.m` before `@implementation`

```
@interface UINavigationController (Private)

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations;
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate;

@end

@implementation UINavigationController (Private)

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```